# Putting awk in a function

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have 4 awks that are really similiar so I want to put them in a function. My awk code is...

```
awk -v MYPATH="$MYPATH" -v FILE_EXT="$FILE_EXT" -v NAME_OF_FILE="$NAME_OF_FILE" -v DATE="$DATE" -v pattern="$STORED_PROCS_BEGIN" '
        $0 ~ pattern {
            rec = $1 OFS $2 OFS $4 OFS $7
            for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) {
                rec = rec OFS $i
                if ($i ~ /\([01]\)/) {
                    break
                }
            }
            print rec >> "'$MYPATH''$NAME_OF_FILE''$DATE'.'$FILE_EXT'"
        }
    ' "$FILE_LOCATION"
```

So the pattern and regular expression differ. How can I put this awk in a function where I can replace pattern with $1 and /([01])/ with $2 if I already use those in my awk?

EDIT: 
I was thinking I can do...

```
 printFmt(){
   awk -v .......
     $0 ~ patten {
        rec..
        for..
           rec..
           if($i ~ search) 
              break
 print rec
```

then call with printFmt set?

```
    }
```

Comment: You already have `pattern` as a variable. Just add one for `/\([01]\)/` too and you should be all set to make it a shell function.

Comment: Oh so I can do printAwk{awk..} and call it with printAwk pattern=blahblah?

Comment: When I was looking online the $1 and $2 automatically became set from parameter 1 and parameter 2 that was passed in

Comment: Not exactly, no. You would use the positional arguments to the function. See [Shell Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) and the following section about [Positional Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters).

Comment: Right, but you can use those in the `-v` arguments to awk the way you are using your hard-coded shell variables now.

Comment: Also, a correction to your script...  You have multiple variables being passed in to the awk script using `-v`, but you aren't using most of them within the script.  For the output of your `print rec` line, you are *escaping* from the single-quoted script in order to use the original shell variables.  Instead, use: `print rec >> MYPATH NAME_OF_FILE DATE "." FILE_EXT;`

Comment: Those variables are listed at the top of my code as "defines" because if someone else uses my program I want them to easily be able to change what file everything gets written to @ghoti

Comment: @EtanReisner can you explain your last statement

Comment: Alan wrt your response to @ghoti - a user would have less trouble understanding and changing them where they belong in the shell part after the script. They have nothing to do with the awk script so don't unnecessarily complicate and tightly couple your code. Do `awk '...print...' "$FILE_LOCATION" > "${MYPATH}${NAME_OF_FILE}${DATE}.${FILE_EXT}"` instead.

Comment: I don't understand why you're struggling with this - you already have a variable named `pattern`, just populate that with the shell function arg `$1` or whatever else you like, and then create a new variable to use in exactly the same way in place of `/\([01]\)/`, that's all. Maybe you're overthinking it?

Comment: @Alan, defining variables in a part of the script you haven't shown us is fine, but the fact remains that you are using `-v` to pass variables into awk, and then you aren't using those variables inside your awk script.  As Ed suggests, you should avoid unnecessary complications, and pick one way or the other to handle this.  (I suggest using the variables within your awk script, and adding validation to those fields somewhere.  I.e. `shopt -s extglob; awk -v MYPATH="${MYPATH%%*(/)}/"`)

Comment: @EdMorton I got it to work just when I changed my /\([01]\)/ to search=/([01])/ it stopped working do you know why?

Comment: You have GOT to get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as right now you're just thrashing around trying bits and pieces of code in various places and hoping magic will occur. Awk has a syntax, the language constructs have meanings - you've got to learn the very basics at least.

Comment: @EdMorton I just thought it was weird I am using the same regular expression but my search results return sometthing diffferent

Comment: @Alan what you're trying to do is fundamentally wrong though and you wouldn't even be trying to do it if you read a few pages of the book. Scalar awk variables are of type "numeric string" and as such ONLY hold numbers or strings. The string delimiter in awk is `"`. If you want to save a string in a variable to be used later as a dynamic regexp then the syntax is `search="([01])"` (and there are caveats - again, read the book). When you write `search=/([01])/` you are telling awk to compare `$0` to the RE `([01])` and save the result (1 or 0) as a number in the variable `search`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where the problem is since you already have in your code exactly what you need to do but maybe this will help by simplifying it a bit:

```
$ cat tst.sh
function prtStuff() {
    awk -v x="$1" 'BEGIN{ print x }'
}

prtStuff "foo"
prtStuff "---"
prtStuff "bar"

$ ./tst.sh
foo
---
bar
```